# Javascript - slidesjs not work on android (ok on all the rest)

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, slidesjs

I am using [SlidesJS](http://slidesjs.com) for a simple slider ...

It works on most browsers (including iOS), but somehow it fails on Android: the sliding actually works, but it displays no images.

The WIP website is [here](http://www.summerconf.com/aurora/).

I would greatly appreciate any input and remarks, as I have absolutely no experience with mobile OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok . after a very long debugging - the problem was caused by google maps embading code .
Specifically by the (otherwise excellent) Google Maps v3 Shortcode plugin .

the plugin injects a css (why???)

```
.entry-content img {max-width: 100000%;  /* override */ }
```

in `function gmaps_header()`

inside file `google-maps-v3-shortcode/Google-Maps-v3-Shortcode.php`

Commenting it out will resolve the problem for android like so :

```
/*.entry-content img {max-width: 100000%;   override  }*/
```

I do not really know WHY it is doing so, and I did not checked all otehr browsers / versions .
I did check chrome , opera and firefox on winxp - and it works fine .
Another method is to put this css inside a conditional browser detection class for andriod.